# How do I debug my test suite when the only info is "Test run failed"?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, junit

I'm writing some jUnit tests for an android app I'm starting on, and I've come up on a *really* weird error.  When I run the test suite in Eclipse (either by right-clicking on the test project -> run as -> Android jUnit test, or by clicking the 'run test' button in the jUnit tab next to Package explorer), it spends a few seconds building and uploading to the emulator, and then just stops with a message in red saying that the "Test run failed".

That's fine, I can live with failure -- except there's *no* other information about what failed.  The jUnit tab doesn't show any test results (no successes, no failures), the 'Problems' tab gives nothing, obviously the thing builds because it loaded into the emulator, the emulator's still running (I opened and closed a couple of apps just to make sure).  I tried running the tests in debug mode (debug as -> Android jUnit test), but no exceptions or errors in there, either.

**Update:** I'm not sure that my test case in the DiagramClassTest is even getting executed, because a breakpoint at the beginning of the method doesn't get hit (yes, I'm running it with Run as -> Android jUnit test).  Yet, there's a runtime error in there.  I'm not overriding the `AndroidTestCase` constructor, or doing anything else funky.

Any suggestions as to what I can try next to get some information on why my tests are failing?  Complete console log below:

```
[2011-02-11 13:43:03 - RosterManagerTest] ------------------------------
[2011-02-11 13:43:03 - RosterManagerTest] Android Launch!
[2011-02-11 13:43:03 - RosterManagerTest] adb is running normally.
[2011-02-11 13:43:03 - RosterManagerTest] Performing android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner JUnit launch
[2011-02-11 13:43:03 - RosterManagerTest] Automatic Target Mode: using existing emulator 'emulator-5554' running compatible AVD 'default'
[2011-02-11 13:43:06 - RosterManagerTest] Application already deployed. No need to reinstall.
[2011-02-11 13:43:06 - RosterManagerTest] Project dependency found, installing: RosterManager
[2011-02-11 13:43:08 - RosterManager] Application already deployed. No need to reinstall.
[2011-02-11 13:43:08 - RosterManagerTest] Launching instrumentation android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner on device emulator-5554
[2011-02-11 13:43:10 - RosterManagerTest] Collecting test information
[2011-02-11 13:43:14 - RosterManagerTest] Test run failed: org.hezmatt.RosterManager.test.DiagramClassTest
```

Comment: How many tests do you have? Try putting a custom message in your assert calls so you know when things are going bad. If it's just not running the test suite at all thats a diff issue

Comment: Where would the output of those custom assert messages appear?  Normally I'd find failed test output in the jUnit tab under "Failure trace", but as I said, there's no test run output -- successes, failures, *anything* -- in that tab at all.

Comment: Can you show us the source code, mainly the constructor.

Comment: Try adding `Log.d()` messages to trace the execution of your tests. You can view these messages using `adb logcat` on the command line. I know you can pull up the log in Eclipse as well, but I don't know the exact menu to click on to do that.